# Does Tiled require everything to be aligned in the source image? Or can I draw a box around various locations?

Tags: tiled

I want to use some artwork I purchased but the person didn't align them to 32x32 tiles. For example, maybe `(100, 100)` to `(228, 324)` has the tiles, and then `(504, 521)` to whatever is the next.

This means I have two options:

1. I manually edit all of the tiles to be aligned in the image
2. There's something in Tiled that lets me specify an offset within some source image for each tile

Does [2] exist? Or am I stuck with [1] above?

Comment: You can adjust the pivot point for sprites in the [SpriteEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html).

Comment: @Mangata, note that the question asks about Tiled, not Unity.

Comment: Aligning images to tiles doesn't sound difficult. I'd just do it. In Gimp: drag box over image, cut, paste, use arrow keys to nudge where you're pasting, click out of paste to finish it... repeat. I think I do remember seeing some kind of offset option inside tiled though.

Comment: @user253751 Normally I would, but there's... a lot... I'd rather see if I can save myself a few hours of work instead of mind-numbingly piece everything together. However it looks like I may be out of luck and will have to do it.